# Command doesnt work as alias or function in bash

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I have this command:

```
# Open up all git modified files in vertical splits
function vge {
  vim -O `git status --porcelain | sed -ne "s/^ M //p"`
}
```

I want to add options and stuff to it later, but I can't even get that to run like that *or* as an alias. It works as is if I just copy the command and paste it into my terminal and hit enter tho. The error I get is the 2nd (and so on) file is:

```
-bash: path/to/file.ext: Permission denied
```

I really have no idea what to try

Comment: and if you do `/bin/ls -l path/to/file.ext` do the permissions look like they should work? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter its "-rw-r--r--"

Comment: and is your personal id the owner of the file, or is a `git admin` the owner of the file?

Comment: `-rw-r--r--  1 oscar  staff  1195` is what I see. `oscar` is my username, if thats what you mean?

Comment: yep, that's what I meant. So `git admin` ownership isn't the issue. Sorry to say, but now it really gets hairy. try `/bin/ls -ld path; ls -ld path/to` and confirm that you see something like `-rwx-r-x-r-x`. If you don't see `--x`, then you can cd into that dir. (Running out of ideas after this). Good luck!

Comment: @shellter why would this work tho pasting into the terminal but not running as a script?

Comment: @shellter Also, I have "permission" to the file that I "dont" have permission to if I reverse the order. Its just whichever files come after the first one dont have permission

Comment: can't chat at work. Yes, that is weird. But I've got to stick with the error msg that you do get.  Do these `/long path/to/file 1.txt` have spaces in them? Else add a `set -vx` on the first line of your function. Maybe you'll see something the. Also use `$( .. cmd ...)` for cmd-substitution (I don't think that will fix it, but join the 90's  ; -) ).

Comment: Going off-line for a while. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you successfully open the first file and then the rest are attempted to be executed. At least, that's the first thing that came to mind when I saw the error message. Then it actually makes sense, since you don't have execute access on the file.

You can verify this by trying it out on some harmless script that has execute permission and see whether it is executed or not.

That said, I don't get that behaviour - it works fine as a function for me, just the way you've written it.

To figure out what's happening, I tend to try to split up the function into separate parts. I also tend to avoid using the backticks for command substitution. I think the $(command) syntax is clearer and less error-prone. That's only a personal preference, though. :)

So, I suggest starting off with something like this:

```
function vge {
    files_to_open=$(git status --porcelain | sed -ne "s/^ M //p")
    echo "Opening files: $files_to_open"
    vim -O $files_to_open
}
```

Check the output and try to figure out why only one file is opened and the rest are executed (if, indeed, that assumption is correct).